# Displaying a mysql row inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have javascript which I need to refrence in my php for users posts, but I need to display the rows information, like shown below. I'm not sure if I need to put this javascript in my php where i'm echo the rows, or something like this. I refrence the javascript using this:

```
<a id='popoverId' class='popoverThis'>Something here</a>
```

So I'm not sure what exactly to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#popoverId').popover({
html: true,
title: '<img src="<?php echo ". $row['cpic'] . "; ?>" height="80px"><h4><a href="/profile?id=2"><img src="/uploads/2/ppic.jpg" height="50px" style="border-top:white 4px solid;"> Wyatt Abraham</a></h4>',
});
$('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function (e) {
if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
$('#popoverId').popover('hide');
}
});
});
</script>
```

I know that what i did above is way off, but any help is great :)

Edit(Exactly what my code looks like at this point):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#popoverId').popover({
html: true,
title: '<img src="<?php echo $row['ppic']; ?>" height="80px"><h4><a href="/profile?id=2"><img src="/uploads/2/ppic.jpg" height="50px" style="border-top:white 4px solid;"> Wyatt Abraham</a></h4>',
});
$('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function (e) {
if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
$('#popoverId').popover('hide');
}
});
});
</script>

<?php
mysql_select_db("*");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");
echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class='container'>


  <div class='bordered'>
    <div class='posts'>";
echo "<img class src='" . $row['ppic'] . "' width='60px'>";           
//. $row['name'] ." ".$row['post'] ."";
echo " ";
echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=". $row['userid'] ."'> " . $row['name'] . "";
echo "</a><hr />";

echo "<a id='popoverId' class='popoverThis'>Something here</a>";

echo "<p class='padding'> " . $row['post'] . "";
echo "</p>";
echo "<div class='foot'>
    <a href='#' class='vbutton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like It!</a><a href='#' class='vbutton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down'></span> Dislike It!</a>";



echo "</div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: What error You are facing???

Comment: Basically the picture i'm trying to reference isn't showing.

Comment: what is the url in img src tag?? may be there is wrong url

Comment: I have the correct url being echoed through the $row['ppic']. it's just the users picture url. So it should be fine, i use the same method in the actual php itself.

Comment: use src="<?php echo $row[\"ppic\"]; ?>" this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: i have to see your output are you working live or in local???

Answer (score 0):

Remove `".` and `."` in your img src like below line

```
<?php echo $row['cpic']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we could give a better awnser if you put the complete script. But if you want to echo your php data just a  `echo $row['cpic'];` would do the job

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript needs to be inside your while() loop.